# Error: React Hook "useState" is called in function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx

I updated the navbar on my site that I developed with NextJs and created header and etc.. then I encountered the following build error.

build error message:

[image]

I did some research and tried various things and I solved the part about useEffect by changing the lines, but then I started getting the above errors. When I researched them, I did not come across very useful results. Below is the code in the header.jsx file.

```
    import NextLink from "next/link";
    import {useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { useRouter } from "next/router";
    import cx from "classnames";
    import IconArrowDropDown from "./icons/arrow-drop-down";
    
    const MENU = {
      "/": "Home",
      "/works": "Works",
      "/resume": "Resume",
      "/post": "Blog",
      "/contact": "Contact",
    };
    
    const header = () => {
      const [isNavOpen, setIsNavOpen] = useState(false);
      const router = useRouter();
    
      const { pathname } = useRouter();
      const clearSlash = pathname.split("/")[1];
      const pathName = clearSlash ? `/${clearSlash}` : "/";
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const handleRouteChangeStart = () => {
          setIsNavOpen(false);
        };
    
        router.events.on("routeChangeStart", handleRouteChangeStart);
        return () => {
            router.events.off("routeChangeStart", handleRouteChangeStart);
        };
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <header>
          <div className="max-w-screen-sm mx-auto flex flex-row justify-between py-6 px-6">
            <NextLink href="/">
              <a className="text-gray-900 text-xl">
                <span className="ml-3 font-bold text-xl">onurhan.dev</span>
              </a>
            </NextLink>
            <nav
              className={cx(
                  isNavOpen ? "flex" : "hidden",
                  "flex-col gap-x-6 sm:!flex sm:flex-row"
              )}
              >
              {Object.keys(MENU).map((path) => {
                  const isActive = path === pathName;
                    return (
                        <span key={path}>
                           <NextLink href={path}>
                                <a className={cx( isActive ? "text-zinc-900" : "text-gray-600" )}>{MENU[path]}</a>
                            </NextLink>
                        </span>
                    );
                })}
            </nav>
    
            {!isNavOpen && (
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="flex bg-zinc-100 text-gray-700 px-3 py-1 rounded-full select-none items-center sm:hidden"
                  onClick={() => {
                    setIsNavOpen(true);
                  }}
                  >
                  <span>{MENU[pathName]}</span>
                  <IconArrowDropDown className="opacity-50" />
                </button>
            )}
          </div>
        </header>
      );
    };
    
    export default header;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom components in React should start with block letter. Try this:

```
const Header = () => {
```

From the docs:

> Note: Always start component names with a capital letter.

React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags.

Comment: Oh my god how careless I am. Thank you so much! When I saw the error code related to useState, I thought it was a state related issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this solution, but maybe try this.
`const [isNavOpen, setIsNavOpen] = useState(false);`

Comment: Thanks for comment but my problem isn't in state. Only `header` functions need to uppercase.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).